# How to add a character to a string only if there aren't any of the same character?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to make a function that checks whether a string has a period in it or not, then if it does not have a period, add one. I can only make it either add infinite periods or not add any at all.

```
function point() {
if (numberOne.indexOf(".") >= 0) {
    numberOne = numberOne + addPoint;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = numberOne;
}}
```

Comment: What is `numberOne` and `addPoint`?

Comment: You could also use the `includes()` method which returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want `== -1` depending on what indexOf returns when there is no match in your language

Right now you say:

- If there is a period in this variable
- Then add a period to this variable
- update the element.

You want to say:

- if I *DON'T* find a "."
- then add a "."

checking `indexOf == -1` or `< 0` should achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

point function should be like this,

```
 function point() {
    if (numberOne.indexOf(".") == -1) {
        numberOne = numberOne + addPoint;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = numberOne;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

indexOf returns -1 if not found. That's why you should compare with -1. that means  period not found.

```
  function point() {
     if (numberOne.indexOf(".") == -1) {
        numberOne = numberOne + addPoint;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = numberOne;
      }
   }
```